# Selenium 2 - checking error messages

Tags: selenium

I want to check error messages. These error messages appear only when my website encounters a problem.

My problem is that I use `findElement` in order to check the error message. So when something goes wrong, Selenium finds it, and everything is O.K.

But when it doesn't (meaning - my website is O.K with no problems) - then Selenium indicates that it doesn't find the element, and rises an exception.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can surround the findElement in a try-catch block, which will do nothing if the element is not found. e.g.

```java
    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
                    try {
                        driver.findElement(by);
                        return true;
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                        return false;
                        //or do nothing
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer [Selenium Webdriver NoSuchElementException](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/problem-catching-selenium-webdriver-nosuchelementexception)

It suggests the following (I've adapted it a bit for your needs) :

```java
List<WebElement> errorElements = driver.findElements(By.id("ERROR_ID"));
if (!errorElements.empty()) {
   // Tests your errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.For this you should design your test case in such a way that you writes code to check error message only when you are sure that you will get error message.

2.But the point is why are you checking for error message when you know that there will be no problem and code will run fine.

3.If you doesn't know that error will occur.. You can place the risky code in try block and write a catch block which will find error message and check it.